# What is TypeAttributes.NotPublic?

Tags: c#, reflection

What access modifier does `TypeAttributes.NotPublic` actually correspond to? `internal`? It seems that `public` and `internal` are the only logical ones on non-nested types, but there is no specific `TypeAttributes.Family`, so does `TypeAttributes.NotPublic` serve the same purpose? Also, will it be true on a type that is also marked `TypeAttributes.NestedFamily`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having a non-nested private class will not make sense, as the class will only be visible to itself (in fact, this will not compile)

We can conclude therefore that `TypeAttributes.NotPublic` defines an **internal** type.

**However**, nested private classes are, on the other hand, quite common, for which you can use `TypeAttributes.NestedPrivate`

Comment: Is `TypeAttributes.NotPublic` exclusive to non-nested classes, or will it also apply for `TypeAttributes.NestedFamily` types?

Comment: @AlphaModder It's exclusive to non-nested classes, that includes `TypeAttributes.Public`, for which there is `TypeAttributes.NestedPublic`

Comment: @AlphaModder Actually, `TypeAttributes.NestedFamily` defines types with family (inheritance) visibility, i.e. **protected**. For the same reason as private types, protected ones can only be nested. For **nested internal**, you should use `TypeAttributes.NestedAssembly`

Comment: @AlphaModder As for the fact of why is it called `TypeAttributes.NotPublic` I really don't have the answer to that question, but I'd suppose because at the end of the day, a top level class can only be public (**public**) or not public (**internal**) to external assemblies.